Definition of Riemann-Liouville derivatives when the function is not smooth
I understand the classical definition of the Riemann-Liouville integral:
$
  {}_{a}D^{\alpha}_{x} f(x) := \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left( {}_{a}I^{n-\alpha}_{x} f(x) \right)
$
as long as $ {}_{a}I^{n-\alpha}_{x} f(x) $ is smooth enough. I'm also familiar with its extension in fractional Hilbert spaces using the Fourier transform. However, something that isn't clear to me is the case where $ {}_{a}I^{n-\alpha}_{x} f(x) $ is not smooth, but it does admit weak derivatives (up to order $ n $). Does this definition, involving classical derivatives, hold when interpreted in the sense of weak derivatives?

This paper may be of interest. It provides a definition of fractional non-Hilbert Sobolev spaces and some embeddings into spaces of integer order
